# Null pointer exception

Tags: android, pointers, exception, null

Hi im new to android programming and all has been smooth until i began getting NPEs . I have scanned the questions and answers relating to this but i have not seen any precise solutions.Most answers are duplicating stuff i already have in textbooks. Any good teacher on this forum to help walk me thru this code ? i need to know what im doing wrong.

My MainActivity.java looks like this:
    package com.westwall.helloworldlist;

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView; 


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private String[] countArray = {"India", "Europe", "Africa"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
R.layout.activity_listview, countArray);

ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.label); 
listView.setAdapter(adapter); 

 }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
int id = item.getItemId();
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

--logcat

```
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:347)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:709)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1580)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:909)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ListView
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:340)
05-02 20:38:13.443: E/AndroidRuntime(377):  ... 30 more
05-02 21:30:31.781: E/ArrayAdapter(406): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
```

Comment: where's your activity_listview?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify your `TextView ID` which you used in your  `R.layout.activity_listview`

Change this :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_listview, countArray);
```

To this :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_listview, R.id.YOUR_TEXT_VIEW, countArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
R.layout.activity_listview, countArray);
```

Because, `ArrayAdapter` requires the third parameter as the the resource ID to be a TextView. Since you didn't specify third parameter i.e `TextView` id here you are getting the error.

If your TextView id is `textView` in `R.layout.activity_listview` like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

then it should be,

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.activity_listview, R.id.textView, countArray);
```

Checkout the third parameter `R.id.textView` which **you were missed in your code**.